# How can I access my Galaxy S5 from a PC to retrieve all of my files?

Tags: files

I broke the digitizer (LCD display/touch sensor underneath glass screen). The phone still turns on and can connect to computer but I can't access it because I have a passcode lock on it and it doesnt give me the option to type it in on my computer. The screen is completely blank and un responsive. Is there anything I can do to retrieve my files?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to backup or access your files from [Kies 3](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) installed on your PC even if it is password protected.

I've also tried it on my Galaxy S4 GT-I9500 and it worked.